# Regex for allowing only particular special characters

Tags: android, regex

Below is the code which I was trying to integrate, if user tries to enter special character. What I want to do is if user tries to enter any special character, it should not allow them to enter any character in edittext.

For that I was thinking of some logic. But below code is what I went for which I dont think is an optimal solution to write it individually for all. Below is getter setter in model class.

```
public String getProfileName() {
    if(profileName != null){
        return profileName.replace("@","");
    }
    return profileName;
}
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: may be: `profileName.replaceAll("\\W+","")`

Comment: can you explain me that regex?

Comment: `\W` matches any non-word character i.e. `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: ohh ok thanks for that, but only one situation in this. Can I pass 3 characters and allow user to enter those three special characters like dash, underscore, space.

Comment: Then use: `profileName.replaceAll("[^\\w\\h-]+","")`

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below regex from @anubhava solved my issue.

```
public String getProfileName() {
if(profileName != null){
    return profileName.replaceAll("[^\\w\\h-]+","");
}
return profileName;
}
```